# Facebook: How to get any pages total likes, ratings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get any facebook page's total likes, ratings,  etc...
I have created a developer account

What I tried:
- Created an app for this.
- Tried to fetch this information using  AppID & AppSecret
- Tried Using access token

I have also done R&D on google and tried many examples but not getting a correct solution which I want.

Pls help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Edit (taken from comment by author):

I tried this example but for every page it requires pageaccesstoken

```
FB.api('/{pagename}?fields=ratings', function (response) {
    Data = response.name; //alert(Data); 
    if (response.error) { 
        alert(response.error.message); 
    } 
}, { access_token: "xxxx|yyyy" });
```

Comment: let us know if you have tried anything , if yes then please share some code as well .

Comment: I tried this example
but for every page it requires pageaccesstoken
FB.api('/{pagename}?fields=ratings', function (response) {
                Data = response.name;
                //alert(Data);
                if (response.error) {
                    alert(response.error.message);
                }
            }, { access_token: "342986686057016|KGxT7XLEXPLNNtGhYXgS_jq5Fio" });

Comment: see my answer. you should delete your comment. btw, never post access tokens. they are meant to be kept secret.

Comment: Included comment in question

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current likes of a Page with a simple App Access Token:

```
/[page-id]?fields=fan_count&access_token=[App-Token]
```

For the ratings of a Page, you need to use a Page Token instead:

```
/[page-id]/ratings&access_token=[Page-Token]
```

More information about Tokens and how to get them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/